# How to obtain file path for .apk file?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

i am trying to install two apk files which are currently in my downloads folder via the adb shell using `adb install path_here.apk`. I've right clicked the files to get the file path however, it saying that it can't find the file to install. Is there a way i can correctly obtain the path?

Answer (score 0):

The path is the folder where the file is currently located, and not some kind of "internal apk path". So, try:

```
adb install folder/where/file/is/located/file.apk
```

Comment: that is what i meant by my question.

Comment: ok so i am not sure if this is the correct way to do it but i moved the two apk files to ../platform-tools folder where my adb is located and accessed the adb shell through the terminal and typed ./adb install nameoffile.apk and it worked

Comment: If you are using a Mac, click the file with the right button, select "Get info", and search for line "Where:" under General Information. I do not have a Windows machine right now, but it is something similar.

Comment: indeed that is what i did

Comment: It worked because now the .apk file and the adb tool have the same path (.../sdk/platform-tools).

Comment: Let's say your .apk file is located under the Desktop folder. Its full path (in Mac) will be `/Users/<your-name>/Desktop/file.apk` (or `~/Desktop/file.apk`, as `~` is an alias to `/Users/<your-name>`). So, your full command would be `adb install ~/Desktop/file.apk`. Clear now?

Comment: i know how to get a file path in mac or on windows, my confusion was that the file path that i put via right click>get info>where: etc didn't work when i tried so i thought maybe i didn't have the right file path and maybe there is an alternative way in retrieving the same information